# Curb gem will not install correctly to use RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, curb

Installed Ruby 2.2.4 x64 Windows.

Installed the correct DevKit.

Installing RVM via Windows...Can't becuase I need the curb gem.

When I install the curb gem I get an error:

[image]

I'm trying to install the RVM from this site, using this command as well:

[image]

When I copy and paste the RVM into the command line i get an error that reads: 'curl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Same thing for the gpg line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the images, and copy/paste the information into your question itself. Images can't be used when we need to copy data for search or reference, and search engines can't use it to help direct others who are searching for a solution to the same problem. "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, will help as will "[mcve]".

Comment: You need to install `curl` and `gpg`, however, being on Windows, RVM's default installation won't work. Per the docs "for Windows use this [tutorial](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/)."

Comment: Okay. Thank you. for both the answer and the advice. I'll make sure I read that before I ask another question. I appreciate the help and information, sincerely. @theTinMan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for windows, pik does manage rvm on windows